# How to create single PredictRequest() with multiple model_spec?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to add multiple model_spec & their respected inputs into single  `predict_pb2.PredictRequest()` as follow:

```
tmp = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()

tmp.model_spec.name = '1'
tmp.inputs['tokens'].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto([1,2,3]))


tmp.model_spec.name = '2'
tmp.inputs['tokens'].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto([4,5,6]))
```

But I'm only getting `2`'s information:

```
>> tmp

model_spec {
  name: "2"
}
inputs {
  key: "tokens"
  value {
    dtype: DT_INT32
    tensor_shape {
      dim {
        size: 3
      }
    }
    tensor_content: "\004\000\000\000\005\000\000\000\006\000\000\000"
  }
}
```

How can I get a single PredictRequest() for multiple models with their respective inputs?

My aim is to create a single request and send it to the tensorflow serving which is serving two models. Is there any other way around this? Creating two separate requests for both models and getting results from tf_serving one after another works, but I'm wondering if I can just combine two requests into one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible. In tensorflow_serving/api/predict.proto, each PredictRequest has only one ModelSpec. You may try to add some code to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using Configuration File.

Contents of Config file can be as shown below:

```
model_config_list {
  config {
    name: 'my_first_model'
    base_path: '/tmp/my_first_model/'
  }
  config {
    name: 'my_second_model'
    base_path: '/tmp/my_second_model/'
  }
}
```

For more information, you can refer the link shown below:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config

Comment: I'm already serving multiple models with the config like above. My question is, how do I make single `predict_pb2.PredictRequest()` which contains input to those `multiple models`. I know how to send single-single requests to any model (sequentially or async) that is available in serving! I'm more interested in sending one GIANT request with multiple inputs for multiple models